# AttributeError: module 'telebot' has no attribute 'TeleBot'

Tags: python, telebot

При попытке запустить Telegram бота, написанного на Python (модуль устанавливался через команду `pip3 install pyTelegramBotAPI`), в терминале появляется ошибка:

> AttributeError: module 'telebot' has no attribute 'TeleBot'

Мой код:

```py
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_echo(message):
    #bot.reply_to(message, message.text)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

bot.polling(none_stop = True)
```

**Дополнение:**
Как позднее выяснилось, это оказались проблемы с блокировкой Telegram на территории РФ. Следует проделать это ещё раз, только с VPN

Comment: Как называется файл, в котором написан этот код?

Comment: @andreymal, файл называется telebot.py

Comment: Переименуйте. .

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI
По-идее все верно, у тебя, случайно проект не называется telebot?
Если это так, то переименуй.

Comment: таже ошибка .ни впн, ни переименовывание не помогает

Comment: Сейчас Телеграм разблокирован на территории РФ, но у меня такая же ошибка. Библиотеки не конфликтуют, telebot.TeleBot а интерпретатор все равно ругается на первую строчку кода